# Maven Ant Task tries to open pom as zip and fails

Tags: java, maven, maven-ant-tasks

I am trying to run an Maven Ant Task with plugin version 2.1.3 and for some reason running into this error:

```
[javac] Compiling 101 source files to /home/raido/Workspace2/foobar/classes
[javac] error: error reading /home/raido/.m2/repository/foobar/1.0/foobar-1.0.pom; error in opening zip file
[javac] 1 error
```

Why is it trying to read a xml file as an zip file and how can I avoid this? The file itself is perfectly fine and readable.

That part from the build.xml file:

```
<target name="compile" depends="init">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}" />
    <javac classpathref="compile.dependency.path" debug="on"
        encoding="UTF-8" 
        deprecation="on" destdir="${classes.dir}"
        includes="bar/**/*.java" optimize="off"
        srcdir="${src.dir}" />
</target>
```

The error is targeted to the closing sign `>` on the `srcdir` row i.e. the whole tag.

Comment: Resolved it but cannot answer it yet due to low rep.

Comment: Added my answer down below. Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The problem was that the main ant file had a specific task that produced JAR-s of the modules but I hadn't done it. This shows how important documentation sometimes is which this project doesn't have at all!

Answer (score 3):

It might be corrupt zip. you can remove the `foobar/1.0/` dir from your maven repos and let maven download new fresh version

Comment: It is a custom POM file and isn't in any other repository than my local one but I'll upload it to a remote location and let maven download it then. But what do you mean by _corrupt zip_? It's just a plain folder with a XML file in it.

Comment: may be you can simply copy and paste the pom and jar and other files into your local maven repos for a quick fix

Answer (score 1):

Show us your definition of `compile.dependency.path`. Seems like the pattern there is not quite correct and allows .pom files (if it's `**/**`, for example), which will clearly not work.